# There is error when trying to make order in django

Tags: python, django, view

When I try to order something, I keep getting this error:

[image]

Here is my views.py

```
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    session = request.session
    cart = session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
    del session['cart']
else:
    customer = request.user.customer
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
        customer=customer, complete=False)

    order_product, created = OrderProduct.objects.get_or_create(
        order=order, )
    order.save()
messages.success(request, 'Заказ успешно оформлен. Проверьте свою электронную почту!!!')
return redirect('product_list')
```

Please can anyone help me to fix this error?

Comment: Can you share your models? Please include code, tracebacks and error messages as formatted text not images

Comment: I edited my question and added my models.py Can you help me now?

Comment: There can be multiple OrderProducts per Order, why do you call `OrderProduct.objects.get_or_create(order=order)` in your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    session = request.session
    cart = session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
    if cart is not None:
        del session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
else:
    customer = request.user.customer
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
        customer=customer, complete=False)

    order_products = OrderProduct.objects.filter(order=order)
    if order_products:
        order_product = order_products[0]
    else:
        order_product = OrderProduct.objects.create(order=order)

    order.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Заказ успешно оформлен. Проверьте свою электронную почту!!!')
    session = request.session
    cart = session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
    if cart is not None:
        # Remove cart items from the session
        del session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
        session.modified = True
  
return redirect('product_list')
```

Comment: I changed it as you said but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Saidcheek, Can you please share the error message here?

Comment: MultipleObjectsReturned at /process/
get() returned more than one OrderProduct -- it returned 2!

Comment: @Saidcheek, Please check the updated answer and use it.

Comment: It is working thank you so much. this means a lot for me. you just saved so many things. but there is one thing. after ordering, products is still in shop cart but products supposed to be deleted after ordering. can you have a look for that too? thank you so much again

Comment: @Saidcheek, Please look at the updated answer. I already updated again.

Comment: I tried updated answer, but now i am getting new error about it. it says "KeyError at /process/
'cart'"

Comment: I believe there is something wrong in the 5th line. (django says that)

Comment: @Saidcheek, What kind of error you are getting now?

Comment: i am getting " KeyError at /process/ 'cart " error

Comment: I am getting  " KeyError at /process/ 'cart " error after your changing. Can you fix it?

Comment: @Saidcheek, Please check again. I added additional check condtion for cart item in session.

Comment: Hello again, sorry to bother you. I am not getting errors after your changing but it was supposed to delete products from the cart after ordering. Now there are still products remaining after the order. can you help me to fix this?

Comment: I hate to say that but it isn't working. there are still products after ordering.

Comment: @Saidcheek, I tried to do my level best here you know. try to find out something by yourself please.